# Deleting dynamic 2D array won't work

Tags: c++

I have a problem with 2D dynamic array. Code is here:

```
//Inicialization
char** arr = new char* [size];
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    arr[i] = new char[70];
```

It is basicly number of sentences with max 70 chars each. Ok... I used it before in that way.
Then I want to delocate it - I did it too!

```
//Deleting
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    delete [] arr[i];
delete [] arr;
```

And this will crash right at i = 0 with:
"Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)".

But as I said - I used it in different project in this way:

```
//Init
char** vety = new char* [pocVet];
for(int i = 0; i < pocVet; i++)
    vety[i] = new char[100];
//Something (again a few sentences).
//Deleting
for(int i = 0; i < pocVet; i++)
    delete [] vety[i];
delete [] vety;
```

I looked everywhere in here and it is the same. What is wrong?
PS: In the second example where it works don't mind different names (in my mother language).

Edit: Maybe it is because of the content of the array? But in the second case (where it works) are the sentences in it either. I just have a bunch of questions in it and user only choose the action - so basicly it is just sentences:

```
arr[0] = " 1 - Use something\n";
arr[1] = " 2 - Use different thing\n";
arr[2] = " 3 - etc...\n";
arr[3] = " 4 - etc\n";
arr[4] = " 5 - etc\n";
arr[5] = " 6 - etc\n";
arr[6] = " 7 - etc\n";
```

I do nothing with it... only printf();

Comment: The problem is with how you use the new array. Because [what you posted works](http://ideone.com/L3tg7j)

Comment: chances are you're stomping on the array pointers somewhere in between the allocation and the subsequent deletion

Comment: Indeed.  I just ran your initial code on 2 compilers.  No problems.  ...[mcve] is called for.

Comment: [Time to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: This is not a 2D array. It would be something like `char (*arr)[70] = new char [size][70];`.

Comment: Look at edit :)

Comment: I'm seeing the problem now, but:  to get a quick, easy answer to your problems, include a [mcve].  There's nothing like it to get people willing to answer your questions, and able to.  ...your assignments into arr[1], etc., throw away your dynamic memory and replace it with static memory.  this causes grief when you try to delete that static memory at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You reassign the pointer `arr[0]` to point to a string literal.

```
arr[0] = " 1 - Use something\n";
```

So you leak the memory  you allocated and then you try to call `delete[]` on memory you didn't allocate.

The solution is to not mess with raw pointers yourself, and instead use the standard library to do the difficult work for you.

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
v.emplace_back(" 1 - Use something\n");
// Other sentences
```

Answer (score 1):

`sprintf` should work for you as long as string literal is of size less than 70.

```
sprintf(arr[0], " 1 - Use something\n");
```